# add values of two columns from 2 different dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to add 2 columns of 2 different dataframes based on the condition that name is same:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([("Apple",2),("Litchi",4),("Orange",6)], columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([("Apple",200),("Orange",400),("Litchi",600)], columns=['a','c'])
```

now i want to add column b and c if the name is same in a.

I tried this `df1['b+c']=df1['b']+df2['c']` but it simply adds column b and c so the result comes as

```
      a    b  b+c
0   Apple  2  202
1  Litchi  4  404
2  Orange  6  606
```

but i want to

```
    a  b+c
0   Apple  202
1  Litchi  604
2  Orange  406
```

i guess i have to use `isin` but i am not getting how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns `b` and `c` are aligned by index values in sum operation, so is necessary create index by  [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `a`:

```
s1 = df1.set_index('a')['b']
s2 = df2.set_index('a')['c']
df1 = (s1+s2).reset_index(name='b+c')
print (df1)
        a  b+c
0   Apple  202
1  Litchi  604
2  Orange  406
```

EDIT: If need original value for not matched values use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) with parameter `fill_value=0`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([("Apple",200),("Apple",400),("Litchi",600)], columns=['a','c']) 
print (df2)
        a    c
0   Apple  200
1   Apple  400
2  Litchi  600

s1 = df1.set_index('a')['b']
s2 = df2.set_index('a')['c']
df1 = s1.add(s2, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='b+c')
print (df1)
        a    b+c
0   Apple  202.0
1   Apple  402.0
2  Litchi  604.0
3  Orange    6.0
```

Comment: but i was looking more of a condition thing, e.g. if i modified df2 as ([("Apple",200),("Apple",400),("Litchi",600)], columns=['a','c']) then for orange i am getting 3  Orange    NaN but for orange it should be 6

Comment: @ShivamRaj - So edited answer not working like you need? Can you explain more what is reason?

Comment: Can't we do a simple merge and then summation?? @jez

Comment: @hacker315 - yes, but I think `add` should be faster.